# finding cause for sometimes slow query

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I am trying to find the cause for a query that is slow, but only sometimes.

I have slow query logging active, and I see the query being logged, for example:

```
timescaledb-2 timescaledb 2023-08-04 13:43:12 UTC [32626]: [64ccfe56.7f72-3] device_monitoring@postgres,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver [00000] LOG:  duration: 27178.742 ms  bind S_9:
```

Sometimes the query times out, my client timeout is set to 30s, so I get:

```
timescaledb-2 timescaledb 2023-08-04 13:33:23 UTC [29788]: [64ccf76c.745c-3] device_monitoring@postgres,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver [57014] ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

Running [explain on the query](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/5e36b5b82fd1d661#plan), I don't see any immediate problems () and the query runs fast most of the times.

I have `pg_stat_statement` active, but these slow executions are never stored:

```
postgres=# select max(max_exec_time) from pg_stat_statements ;
-[ RECORD 1 ]----
max | 2286.040693
```

That is only about 2 seconds. Do I need to activate any setting for slow queries to be included in `pg_stat_statement`?

I have `log_lock_waits` set to `on`, but no slow locks are logged.

What else can be the cause of these slow queries?

Comment: If a bind is very slow, that is strange. Perhaps the CPU is hopelessly overloaded.

Comment: pg_stat_activity doesn't have io stats.  Did you mean pg_stat_statements?

Comment: cpu usage is very low, and the problem is this only happens some times. What do you mean the bind is low? Because of bind S_9? How can I debug that?
yes I meant pg_stat_statements, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by server side prepared statements. It seems ts/psql caches the exec plan of the first query. jdbc then uses that prepared statement with an older plan and just provides bind parameters, but the plan is not efficient for the newer values.
I used `prepareThreshold=0` with the jdbc driver and the problem seems to be fixed.